# Syntax difference in React for export module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between the 2 following syntaxes and does it matter ?

```
const Home = (props)=>{
  return (
   <div>Balbal {props.test}</div>
  )
}

**module.exports= Home;**

const Home = (props)=>{
  return (
   <div>Balbal {props.test}</div>
 )
}

**export default Home**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is the 'old' export syntax used by [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/) to share objects and functions.  The second is the more recent [ES6 modules](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/) syntax that is built-in to JavaScript.

Functionally, they are identical, but the second may be considered more idiomatic now, where supported.

Answer (score 0):

1st one is named export. You can export multiples classes or variables while `export default` is used to export single Class/variable. See here for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export